# Stop a Docker container that's been running for a certain amount of time

Tags: bash, docker

I'd like to create a cron job that would stop Docker containers if they've been running for more than, say, 2 hours.

I can get the times they started.

`$ docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' $(docker ps -q)`

Just need to compare that with 2 hours ago...

`$ date --utc --date="-2 hours" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ"`

...and if it's earlier stop the container

`$ docker stop <<container_id>>`

How can I do this with a bash script?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4):

It is an old thread but still if someone is searching for an answer. The below command will stop containers running more than 2 hours.

```
docker ps --format="{{.RunningFor}} {{.Names}}"  | grep hours |  awk -F: '{if($1>2)print$1}' | awk ' {print $4} ' | xargs docker stop
```

Explaination:

```
docker ps --format="{{.RunningFor}} {{.Names}}"
```

will print the container names and running period.

```
grep hours
```

will print the containres running in hours.

```
 awk -F: '{if($1>2)print$1}'
```

will only print containers running for more than 2 hours.

```
awk ' {print $4} ' | xargs docker stop
```

will print the container names obtained from previous output and pass it as argument to stop the containers.

Comment: your answer will stop the containers running for X amount of hours, but not the ones running Y amount or weeks, or Z amount of months.

Comment: This is also dangerous because of the inclusion of `.Names`. If that free text name happens to include the string `hours` it will be killed if the first value is >2. Better to use `"{{.RunningFor}} {{.ID}}"`

Answer (score 1):

This was discussed as soon as 2013 in [issue 1905](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1905)

The bash alternative was:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

to=$1
shift

cont=$(docker run -d "$@")
code=$(timeout "$to" docker wait "$cont" || true)
docker kill $cont &> /dev/null
echo -n 'status: '
if [ -z "$code" ]; then
    echo timeout
else
    echo exited: $code
fi

echo output:
# pipe to sed simply for pretty nice indentation
docker logs $cont | sed 's/^/\t/'
```

with:

```
$ docker-run-timeout.sh 10s busybox sh -c 'echo start && sleep 30 && echo finish'
status: timeout
output:
    start
```

Note, with docker 1.13, you could run with `--rm -d` (see [PR 20848](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/20848)).

Answer (score 1):

The one-liner from @Siru is great, however I had to change below part in order to correctly find containers older than two digit number of days:

```
awk -F " " '{if($1>14)print$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

@siru's solutions inspired me to look for an option to be persice about the exact time to control for, since the docker ps `running for` is a rounded formatted result and not exact:

```
docker ps -q | xargs docker inspect --format='{{.Id}} {{.State.StartedAt}}' |\
 awk '{"date -d " $2 " +%s" | getline startedAt
 "date +%s" | getline now
 if((now-startedAt)/(60*60) > 5) print $1}' |\
 xargs docker rm -f
```

explination:

The first line will pass a list of container Id's and their started time in ISO 8601 format.

Then we convert each date to UNIX time, calculate the delta from the current time, and pass on to `docker rm -f` only the lines where the running time exceeded the time specified.

In this example, all containers that are running more than 6 hours will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping to do this within the Go templating of the format string, but I don't think we have any time parsing functions included (might make for a nice PR).

Instead, here's a version that takes advantage of the date command for time parsing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# adjust threshold as needed
threshold="2 hours"
# cutoff is seconds since epoc of the threshold time
cutoff="$(date --date="-$threshold" "+%s")"
# loop through the running containers by id
docker container ls -q | while read cid; do
  # retrieve the start time as a string
  startedat="$(docker container inspect "$cid" --format "{{.State.StartedAt}}")"
  # convert to seconds since epoc
  start="$(date --date="$startedat" "+%s")"
  # then we can do a numeric comparison in shell
  if [ "$start" -lt "$cutoff" ]; then
    docker container stop "$cid"
  fi
done
```

For other examples of using date to calculate offsets, see [this post in unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49053/how-do-i-add-x-days-to-date-and-get-new-date).

Answer (score 0):

I used this simple method (derived from [Siru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911259/1695049)) to stop anything running for more than 24hrs.

`docker ps --format="{{.ID}} {{.RunningFor}}" | grep "day\|week\|month" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker stop`

If you ran this as well as [Siru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64911259/1695049) then you can reliably clean up to a specific number of hours, but at that point it's probably be better to use [Itiel's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70402162/1695049).

Comment: There's a case where the docker ps shows 33 hours ago, but not "day", so your solution will not catch that.

Answer (score 0):

The below `bash` function

- takes the number of days as an input argument,
- iterates all containers,
- compares the time the container was started against the current time minus `n` days, and
- stops the container if it has been running for more than `n` days.

```bash
function docker-stop-running-for-n-days() {
    date_threshold=$(date --utc --date="$1 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

    for name in $(docker ps --format="{{ .Names }}"); do

        start_date=$(docker inspect -f '{{ .State.StartedAt }}' "$name")

        printf "Stopping container:\n"

        if [[ "$start_date" < "$date_threshold" ]]; then
            docker stop "$name"
        fi
    done
}
```